# Rails 4 Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, controller

I'm fairly new to rails and into coding my first app. Just can't figure out how to target a user the current_user favorited (Three models: User, Tool, FavoriteUser).

Controller (Tools)

```
def index
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @tools = Tool.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  @user = FavoriteUser.find(params[:c_user_id]).user_id
  @cuser = current_user
end
```

Index View (Tools)

```
%h2 My Favorite Users
- @userfavorites.each do |user|
    = image_tag gravatar_for @user if @user.use_gravatar == true
    = image_tag @user.avatar_filename.url if @user.use_gravatar == false
    %h2= link_to @user.username, @user
    %p= link_to "Favorite", @userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Unfavorite", @userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
```

If I run this in my browser it appears following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ToolsController#index
Couldn't find FavoriteUser with 'id'=
```

**EDIT:**

FavoriteUser Database:

```
user_id:integer #favorited
c_user_id:integer #active user
```

I simply can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance for your help!

**ADDED RELATIONSHIPS:**

*user.rb*

```
has_many :favorite_users # just the 'relationships'
  # Favorite users of user
  has_many :favorite_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "c_user_id"
  has_many :userfavorites, through: :favorite_relationships, source: :user

  # Favorited by a user
  has_many :favorited_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :userfavorited_by, through: :favorited_relationships, source: :c_user
```

*favorite_user.rb*

```
class FavoriteUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :c_user, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
end
```

Comment: It says, `params[:c_user_id]` is `nil` in your controller action. Can you copy and paste `params` from the logs which are coming to your action?

Comment: @RAJ How can it be nil? Added these params to the question

Comment: I assume you are hitting `/tools` URL in your browser, in which `c_user_id` param is not present that's why `params[:c_user_id]` is nil. Can you paste params from logs? Also confirm that what URL you are hitting.

Comment: I hit localhost:3000. Is thet what you need? irb(main):004:0> FavoriteUser.first
  FavoriteUser Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "favorite_users".* FROM "favorite_users"  ORDER BY "favorite_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<FavoriteUser id: 1, c_user_id: 1, user_id: 2, created_at: "2016-09-06 05:11:35", updated_at: "2016-09-06 05:11:35">
irb(main):005:0>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's the solution!

```
@userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have setup your relationships correctly, following solution should work for you.

Replace:

```
@user = FavoriteUser.find(params[:c_user_id]).user_id
```

with

```
# Returning complete user object instead of only user's id,
# as it's getting used on the view
@user = current_user.favorite_user
```

Comment: The relationships are working (tested in the console) but to me it seems you cant do what you did. I get an undefined method error

Comment: I'll add the relationships to the question real quick

Answer (score 0):

```
params[:c_user_id]
```

is nil when this controller action is invoked.  You have to send it through if you want to access it.  If you put this line at the top of your controller action

```
puts "#{params[:c_user_id]}"
```

you will see params[:c_user_id] is nil.

Comment: How on earth am i able to do that? In the model? I have done this in the User model: 
  `has_many :favorite_users # just the 'relationships'
  # Favorite users of user
  has_many :favorite_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "c_user_id"
  has_many :userfavorites, through: :favorite_relationships, source: :user

  # Favoritad by a user
  has_many :favorited_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :userfavorited_by, through: :favorited_relationships, source: :c_user`